# Laravel spark chrome csrf invalid

Tags: php, google-chrome, vue.js, laravel-5.3, laravel-spark

Firefox and IE 11/Edge are behaving correctly.

But when I attempt to log in to my Laravel spark app from Chrome, I am able to the first time, but am immediately told my session is expired, it kicks me out to the login screen, then every subsequent login receives an invalid CSRF token warning.

Laravel is not outputting any errors in the log. I'm stumped honestly.

Any ideas why only chrome is having these issues? I'm assuming it's some kind of cookie issue.

Comment: I just tried this from my home computer and it's working fine. I'm going to assume my work computer needs a reboot and try again tomorrow.

Comment: how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask